# Nuxt: Page crashing on page reload

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

Anyone know why a sub page crashes when user reloads the page? It is fine when you navigate to the page using nuxt-link from another page (using route params), but when the user reloads/refreshes the page, it will crash.

Here is my sandbox where you can test it out: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-nash-4mwol)

Code from nuxt link:

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{name: 'photos-id-title', params: { id: photo.id, title: photo.title }}">
```

Code from photo details page:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <!-- <template v-if="photo"> -->
    <img
      :id="photo.filename"
      :src="photo.url"
      class="img-fluid thumbnail rounded"
      :alt="photo.title"
    />
    <h1 class="h3">{{ photo.title }}</h1>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { Annotorious } from '@recogito/annotorious'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      photo: {},
      anno: {},
      title: this.$route.params.title
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getPhotoDoc()
    this.anno = await new Annotorious({ image: this.photo.filename })
  },
  methods: {
    async getPhotoDoc() {
      const docRef = await this.$fireStore
        .collection('photos')
        .doc(this.$route.params.id)
        .get()
      try {
        if (docRef.exists) {
          // data() returns all data about the doc
          console.log('got the doc: ', docRef.data())
          this.photo = docRef.data()
        } else {
          console.log('no docs exist')
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error getting document:', error)
      }
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.photo.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: this.photo.description
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

User journey: Click PHOTOS from navbar, select any photo on the page. You shall see a "photo detail" page. Loads fine. Try to refresh the page -- it will crash.

Note: I also have this scaffolded in a regular/plain vue app using Vue-cli and have NO issues. Only seems to be a problem with Nuxt. Must be SSR related?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: It's SSR related, because of the fact that the page crash only on reloads. Can you give us some errors or fix the codesandbox link ?

Comment: Sorry about the link...didn't know it was private. Try it now! https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-nash-4mwol

Comment: So it SEEMS the issue is the Annotorious Plugin I"m using. It is fine in Vue app, but not Nuxt. Am I not loading the plugin correctly? If you disable that plugin everything works fine.

Comment: Be carefull all your API keys are in your codesandbox

Comment: Thanks. I dont' think it's an issue. Google docs for Firebase said there are no secrets there.

Answer (score 2):

If you think this is SSR related and the Annotorious plugin might cause the problem try this:

1. `nuxt.config.js` add the plugin with mode `client`

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/client-only.js', mode: 'client' }, // only on client side
  ]
```

You can find more information in the nuxtjs docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/)

Comment: Would it be better if I Just used a CDN for this plugin? https://recogito.github.io/annotorious/getting-started/

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference tbh. Some plugins might work only in the browser because they lack SSR support. Just check the [nuxtjs docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#name-conventional-plugin) and give it a try :)

Comment: I am not sure I'm doing this right. First, I need to create a plugin like so?
`import Vue from 'vue'
import Annotorious from '@recogito/annotorious'
Vue.use(Annotorious)` ?

Comment: Create a new file in the `plugins` directory and add this `import Vue from 'vue' import Annotorious from '@recogito/annotorious' Vue.use(Annotorious)` to the file. Then simply add it to the `plugins` array in the `nuxt.config.js` like i suggested above.

Comment: Yea, it's not working. I'm going to make a new question and will also start with a clean slate. If you don't mind, I'll ping you with the link when ready. Thanks for your previous help!

Comment: sure no problem :) !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62833892/how-to-import-third-party-plugin-into-nuxt-and-initialize-during-mounted-hook