# How to import third party plugin into Nuxt and initialize during mounted hook?

Tags: nuxt.js

What is the correct way to use a third party plugin with Nuxt? I consulted the Nuxt plugin documentation, but it is not working for me.

Let me explain:

I am trying to use a JavaScript image annotation library called [Annotorious](https://github.com/recogito/annotorious) and the Annotorious docs state to use the plugin like so:

```
import { Annotorious } from '@recogito/annotorious';

const anno = new Annotorious({ image: 'hallstatt' }); // image element or ID
```

I created a plugin named `annotorious.client.js` and placed it in my `plugins` folder:

> plugins/annotorious.client.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Annotorious from '@recogito/annotorious'
Vue.use(Annotorious) <-- am I supposed to be doing it like this?
```

> Then, in `nuxt.config.js` file I added:

`plugins: ['~/plugins/annotorious.client.js']`.

> Then, in my Nuxt page I tried to initialize the plugin like so:

```
<template>
...snip...
    <img :id="photo.filename" :src="photo.url" />
...snip...
</template>

<script>
    import Annotorious from '~/plugins/annotorious.client.js'
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          photo: {},
          anno: {}
        }
      },
      async mounted() {
        await this.getPhoto()
        this.anno = new Annotorious({ image: this.photo.filename })
```

Note: IN a regular Vue app (built with Vue-Cli), everything works great. However, once I tried to use Nuxt I get issues. Here's a console error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined
    at Function.Vue.use (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5106)
    at eval (annotorious.client.js?8beb:3)
    at Module../plugins/annotorious.client.js (default~app.js:4509)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:854)
    at fn (runtime.js:151)
    at eval (index.js:46)
    at Module../.nuxt/index.js (default~app.js:203)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:854)
    at fn (runtime.js:151)
    at Module.eval (client.js:49)
```

Anyone spot anything in my code? How to get this working? I would throw up a codesandbox but their Nuxt starter is broken. Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just quickly setup a new nuxt project and the simple approach [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#vue-plugins) did just not work.

So I tried to inject it like this:

`plugins > annotorious.js`

```
import { Annotorious } from '@recogito/annotorious';

export default (context, inject) => {
    const initAnnotorious = (id) => new Annotorious({ image: id });
    inject('initAnnotorious', initAnnotorious)
    // For Nuxt <= 2.12, also add 
    context.$initAnnotorious = initAnnotorious
}
```

in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/annotorious.js', mode: 'client' },
  ]
```

and then in your component:

```
<template>
    <img id="hallstatt" src="https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/xwpv_top-650x363.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+ws+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.1-Of_zmw5H.png" alt="">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    var anno = this.$initAnnotorious("hallstatt");
    console.log(anno)    
  }
}
</script>
```

You can read more about this approach [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#inject-in-root-amp-context)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Wow that works! That was the one thing i did not try based on docs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Annotorious is **not** a Vue plugin, so no you should not use `Vue.use(Annotorious)`.

The reason you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install'` is because Vue attempts to call the `install` function on the object you pass to `Vue.use`.

Try to just import Annotorious in you component and use it. You can also import in the `mounted` hook in case the library uses functions objects that are not defined on the server.